# How to remove 'Chapter 1.' from 'Chapter 1. Introduction' while using \leftmark?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\newcommand{\currentchapter}{}
%\let\oldchapter\chapter
%\renewcommand{\oldchapter}[1]{\oldchapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#1}}

%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textbf{#1}}{}} \rhead{\leftmark} 

\fancypagestyle{newstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
}
\begin{document}
```

I want to have

> 'Introduction'

in place of

> 'Chapter 1. Introduction'

as the header for my pages inside the document.
So, is there a command set I can use instead of `\leftmark` to get the desired results? Or can I redefine `\leftmark` in any way to get the desired results?

Comment: Would using `\chapter*{Introduction}` solve your problem?

Comment: Can you please add more information for the example? What's the purpose of `\currentchapter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your current (re)definition of `\chapter` is that it removes the ability to use `\chapter*{<title>}` or `\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<title>}`. While this may not be a problem in your case, a general approach/solution would be preferred.

[`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides built-in access to the titles of sectional units via `\chaptertitle`, `\sectiontitle`, etc.:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{newstyle}{
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
  \sethead[\chaptertitle]% even left
    []% even centre
    [\thepage]% even right
    {\thepage}% odd left
    {}% odd centre
    {\sectiontitle}% odd right
}

\pagestyle{newstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

In fact, even though the above does not use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), the switch to `titleps` is fairly straight forward. See [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html). The advantage should be obvious, since the interface provided by `titleps` is clear and avoids hacking into the page marks to extract content.

Comment: Sorry Sorry !!! I was totally exhausted when I posted this question that I was in a hurry and I was not clear enough. I want to use the chapter name in the header and I know that \leftmark gives me the chapter name. but, it also gives me an unwanted word - the chapter number. I just want the chapter name and want to remove the chapter number from the command \leftmark. I have made come edit to the code that I posted above(it was actually the methods I tried to get this result)

Comment: @newbie: But that's exactly what [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides in my answer. `\chaptertitle` gives *only* the chapter title (no number and no `CHAPTER` prefix). So no need to be sorry...

Comment: Big thanks.. Thanks for the example pictures also.. LIFESAVER answer.. Works PERFECT

Comment: This is exactly what I need except that I would like centered headers, where should I change the code?